# Asp.net core publish creates all dll files in publish folder in visual studio 2017

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-mvc

When publishing Asp.net core mvc application to the folder it creates all .dll files to the output folder

i am using

Visual Studio 2017 15.5.4

Project framework .Net 4.7.1

How to avoid the creating all not required .net framework related .dll?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there a way to have those dll:s output to some folder like bin instead?

Answer (score 4):

The [`publish` command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-publish?tabs=netcore2x) in dotnet core compiles the application and copies all dependencies to the output folder. Since dotnet core is extremely lightweight (as far as the core framework), most (if not all) dependencies are actually NuGet packages. Since these can't be assumed to exist on the machine where the published app is going, they are copied too.

If the `publish` command has copied the files to the output directory, they are required by the application to run. You can add options such as `--no-dependencies` or `--no-restore`, but the resulting published files may not be able to run.

If you are looking to reduce the size of published applications, there is the [.NET IL Linker](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/samples/linker-instructions.md) project that might be able to help.

Comment: tried --no-depn and --no-restore still all files are copied. used "dotnet publish -c release -f net471 --no-dependencies  -r win81-x64". don't know why. even if i have visual studio 2017 do i have have publish from command line using .net core build engine?